# Post request array length 100 000 not happening

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, http-post

I tried to AJAX post the array data of very large amount(length 100 000) to server to save that it into db, but post request itself aborting.

Also we have made settings in server conf post_max_size = 200 MB, upload_max_filesize=200MB, our data seems close to 180 MB.

(if array.length=100, then same post works).

How to post such large amount data to server ?